# How to make multiple tooltips that follow cursor?

Tags: html, css, tooltip, mouseover, mousemove

I want to make multiple tooltips in one HTML page, but because the id is unique it won't allow me to do so. How can I change this?

An example of the code

```
<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
Google
<span id="tooltip-reveal">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</span>
</a>
```

An example of the style

```
 .tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}

.tooltip span {
display:none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and the JS, which I am having troubles with.

```
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-reveal');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

Thank you.

```js
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-reveal');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

```css
 .tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}

.tooltip span {
display:none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
Google
<span id="tooltip-reveal">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to vote on an answer if any of them helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since ID's are unique to a page, it's best to use Classes because they can be reused throughout a page. This JS looks for the class instead of ID. Also note that the link was set to a block so there's more space around it.

```js
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip-reveal");

window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;

  for (var i = 0; i < tooltipSpan.length; i++) {
    tooltipSpan[i].style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan[i].style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  }

};
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}

.tooltip {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
Google
<span class="tooltip-reveal">
    <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</span>
</a>


<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">
Stack Overflow
<span class="tooltip-reveal">
    <img alt="" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded" />
</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use class instead of id, but be more specific in the query:

```js
var tooltipSpans = document.querySelectorAll('a.tooltip>.tooltip-reveal');

window.onmousemove = function(e) {

  tooltipSpans.forEach(function(element, index) {
    let x = e.clientX
    let y = e.clientY;
    element.style.top = (y + 20 * index) + 'px';
    element.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
  })

};
```

```css
.tooltip {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip span {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
Google
<span class="tooltip-reveal">
    first tooltip
</span>
<span class="tooltip-reveal">
    second tooltip
</span>
</a>
```